# Certain commands (e.g. modprobe or usermod) fail as late-commands in Ubuntu autoinstall

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, iso

I am attempting to set up [containerd for kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd) through [Ubuntu's autoinstall mechanism](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#late-commands) (for Ubuntu 20.04).

Some commands when used in `late-commands` seem to fail without obvious reason. (Exit > 0 with no descriptive output.) The failing snippet from `late-commands` looks like:

```
  late-commands:
    - printf 'overlay\nbr_netfilter\n' > /target/etc/modules-load.d/containerd.conf
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- /usr/sbin/modprobe overlay
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- /usr/sbin/modprobe br_netfilter
```

The installer errors out showing that the `modprobe` call exits 1.

[image]

I restart the VM, log in as `ubuntu`, and become `root`. At that time I can run `modprobe overlay` successfully (exit 0). I also cannot see `/var/crash/16238...` (see above) as it does not appear to exist on the target. (I'm guessing it exists in the installer environment.) `/var/log/installer` contains nothing useful either.

Given the above, what it is that might make `modprobe` fail as a `late-command`? Seemingly unrelatedly, I've also tried a `chage -d 0` call that failed with zero error message also. Is there some explanation for why some commands may not exist or not work properly within the target environment at that stage?

---

Edit 1: regarding the usermod failure, I'm guessing as this reply hints at that the ubuntu user is not created at that point in the install process.

Edit 2: I added an `error-commands` which seems useful for debugging:

```
  error-commands:
    - /usr/bin/tail -n 250 /var/log/syslog
```

This now shows `Module overlay not found in /lib/modules/...`:

[image]

Comment: Read the `/var/crash/` file mentioned on the last line of your picture. It's a text file, so you can use `less`.

Comment: The file doesn't exist as advertised on the target, as indicated in my question. I believe it sits in the installer environment, which I can't access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is that modprobe was looking in the wrong place due to an updated kernel prior to reboot.

During the install process, you can use `CTRL+Z` to get into a Bash shell as the root user in the *installer*. In this environment, `/cdrom` is the mounted ISO (iso9660), and `/target` is the root of the target filesystem. This is a great way to debug `curtin in-target` commands, which internally are basically a `chroot /target` call.

In the case of modprobe, the output shows:

```
modprobe: FATAL: overlay module not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic
```

While this directory does exist on the *installer*, on the target what actually exists is:

```
/target/lib/modules/5.4.0-80-generic
```

Notice the slight change in kernel version that modprobe has not detected. I believe this is due to kernel updates during the install process.

As a fix for this specific command, `modprobe` enables you to set the version:

```
curtin -v in-target --target=/target \
    -- /usr/sbin/modprobe --set-version 5.4.0-80-generic overlay
```

With `--set-version` the command will run successfully and exit 0.