# rsyslog.service not found by Ansible during preseed late_command

Tags: 18.04, systemd, preseed, ansible

I continually find that certain things "just don't work" when run as `preseed/late_command` in an Ubuntu Bionic preseed file. (The same applies to autoinstall for Ubuntu Focal.) In this particular case, I'm attempting to run an Ansible Role (specifically, the [Canonical Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for Ansible STIG](https://public.cyber.mil/stigs/downloads/)) against the target as a `late_command`:

```
d-i    preseed/late_command    string \
    in-target /usr/bin/curl -fsSL -o /opt/stig.zip {{ di_preseed.stig_role_url }}; \
    in-target /usr/bin/unzip -qq /opt/stig.zip -d /opt; \
    in-target /usr/bin/unzip -qq /opt/ubuntu1804STIG-ansible.zip -d /opt; \
    in-target /bin/sh -c -- 'cd /opt && ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=/var/log/ansible.log /bin/sh enforce.sh'
```

Here `enforce.sh` is just a wrapper around `ansible-playbook`.

This install from ISO on Virtualbox fails with:

```
Failed to run preseeded command ... <command> finished with exit code 2
```

I am still able to log in to the box as `ubuntu` and become `root`. I see that Ansible was successfully installed (it is originally specified in `pkgsel/include`).

I then open up `/var/log/installer/syslog` on the target and find that `ansible-playbook` failed when it could not find `rsyslog.service`:

[image]

This is confusing as `rsyslog.service` is most certainly enabled and active after the install, which I can confirm with `systemctl (status|is-active) rsyslog`.

**So what I'm seeking to understand here is:**

- Why is Ansible unable to find `rsyslog.service` during install even though it appears to be enabled?
- What factors are different about the installation that result in things seeming to commonly break or not be available?
- Would I be better of running this as an onboot script under init.rc, then last line it removes itself after done?

---

Related: [Certain commands (e.g. modprobe or usermod) fail as late-commands in Ubuntu autoinstall](https://askubuntu.com/q/1346355/919528)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to remember is that the `in-target` commands are executed in a `chroot` environment.  They are not executed in a fully booted system where core processes like systemd are running and available.

**Testing**

I setup a playbook based on the STIG tasks in the screenshot and ran it from the preseed.  I saw the same results as you.

- Playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: check if rsyslog.service is installed
      shell: ! systemctl list-unit-files | grep "^rsyslog.service[ \t]\+"
      changed_when: False
      check_mode: no
      register: result
      failed_when: result.rc > 1

    - name: stigrule_219160_rsyslog_enable
      service:
        name: rsyslog.service
        enabled: "yes"
```

- Partial preseed file

```
d-i pkgsel/include string ansible
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    wget -P /target/ http://REDACTED/my_playbook.yml ; \
    in-target ansible-playbook -i /dev/null -b -v /my_playbook.yml
```

Bionic packages ansible `2.5.1` and [that version of the service module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/ed473d792bbe9c0b9a51084a362e3b2cb85f626c/lib/ansible/modules/system/service.py#L536) appears to execute `systemctl show rsyslog.service`.  This does not work in a chroot environment.  To demonstrate, if I open a terminal in the installer environment and run `in-target systemctl show rsyslog.service` then the log file will show the output

```
in-target: Running in chroot, ignoring request: show
```

**Potential Fix**

I did find a patch in Ansible 2.3 that [addresses the problem](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/21072) that systemctl will ignore commands when running in a chroot environment.  This was only applied to the `systemd` module though and not the `service` module.  I updated my playbook and this does run successfully.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: check if rsyslog.service is installed
      shell: ! systemctl list-unit-files | grep "^rsyslog.service[ \t]\+"
      changed_when: False
      check_mode: no
      register: result
      failed_when: result.rc > 1

    - name: stigrule_219160_rsyslog_enable fixed
      systemd:
        name: rsyslog.service
        enabled: "yes"
```

Therefore, you may be able to progress further by modifying the STIG task(s) from using the `service` module to using the `systemd` module.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. I had a breakthrough when i discovered today that `ctrl+z` will get you into a bash shell as root in the installer environment with /cdrom and /target sitting on the filesystem (the former being the mounted iso). That opened up a whole lot of easier debugging including discovering, as you mention here, that most of systemctl isn't available in a chroot environment. So that's not an ansible problem, per se, and the fact that curtin in-target is a chroot /target under the hood seems to be the underlying cause of most behavioral issues I've encountered.

Comment: FWIW, we'll likely choose to go the route of using ansible from a separate control node via ssh (as it's really supposed to be done, I would argue) after the installation process has completed for a group of nodes and they are accessible via ssh, where chroot is out of the picture.

Comment: Thanks to being able to get into the installer shell I've now been able to solve this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/1355980/919528. You might find that interesting

Comment: @BradSolomon I do think running ansible from a control node will be less problematic.  There should be an option to open a shell from the "Help" drop-down in the installer UI.  I usually just use `Alt-F2`.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1257186/376778 .  You can even SSH into the installer environment if you set (or capture) the `installer` user password (YMMV depending on subiquity version): https://askubuntu.com/a/1322129/376778